# Are lvalues determined at compile time?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation, compile-time, lvalue

In my understanding, an lvalue is just a location, and its corresponding rvalue is the  value stored at that location. for example:

```
int x;
x = 0; /* the compiler will replace x with the location where 0 will be stored */
int y = x; /* x works as an rvalue here, its content is unknown until run time */
```

Can the compiler known at compile time that the value of x is 0 in the third line, so that it can initialize y with the value 0 directly (instead of wait until run time, and at run time first get the value of x then give that value to y)?

```
int *p = &x;
*p = 3;
```

Here *p in the second line is a lvalue (the location of x). Since &x is known at compile time, so *p is also known at compile time, right?

Will the compiler simply replace *p with x's location, or will it generate code that first get the address stored in p, then assign 3 to that address?

Comment: Look at the assembly produced.

Comment: In both of these cases the compiler will more than likely simply throw out as much unneeded intermediate junk as possible and boil the code down considerably. In the first case, unless `x` is used elsewhere I'd be surprised if it was even *in* the final bits. Likewise with `p` in the second. Think about that, then see chris' comment.

Comment: It can perform this optimization, but it doesn't have anything to do with value categories of expressions. What makes you think the location of an object is always known at compile-time?

Comment: I'd guess a good compiler would optimize out any (de-)referencing and access the location directly ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want has to do with lvalues or rvalues. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm sensing you want to do some "manual optimizations" by ensuring, coarsely speaking, that things that are determined at compile-time don't take any computation at run-time. There are many ways to do that, some more complicated than others.

From the two examples that you posted, I would advise that you take an interest in const and static qualifiers, and in the new [constexpr](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-compile-time-processing-with-constexpr.html) key-word in C++11. Generally speaking, never forget to write `const` when you can; it really helps the compiler during optimization. For `static` it's another story; it turns out to be safer for everyone if you use it only if you are already quite experienced in programming, only in some specific cases, and some are religiously against using it altogether...

If you want to know a little more about optimization, I would recommend [this website](http://www.tantalon.com/pete/cppopt/main.htm), and of course there is also [template-meta-programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Templates/Template_Meta-Programming) which can help make some computation happen at compile-time.

To go back to your example, why would you write such a thing and expect the compiler to do the work for you? If you know `y` is 0, why not write it yourself? If the value of `y` is going to change later on, how would you do otherwise than allocating space for `y` in memory, and copy the value 0 at this location when your code "starts" using it (at runtime, that is)? What if the value of `y` was set depending on a condition that could only be resolved at run-time? Etc.

Optimization is really exciting, true, but it should not come first in a development. If you have programmed something, and that you think it could run faster, then ask yourself how, but most of the time, it's useless (and dangerous, and inefficient) to try and optimize each instruction.

"*More computing sins are committed in the name of efficiency (without necessarily achieving it) than for any other single reason - including blind stupidity.*", W.A. Wulf

Answer (score -2):

I would not say that in the expression `int y = x` the variable `x` is an r-value. The fact that it is on the right-hand side does not mean that it is an r-value.

By definition, an l-value is *an object that occupies some identifiable location in memory*, such as `x`; r-values are simply *objects which are not l-values*.

So if the expression were `int y = x1 + x2`, then, yes, the temporary `x1 + x2` would be an r-value, but in your case, and for the lifetime of the scope in which `x` is defined, `x` has an identifiable location in memory and is thus an l-value.

Comment: rvalues have a location in memory too. That's why you can take references and pointers to them.

Comment: x is both an lvalue and an rvalue. The lvalue to rvalue conversion is implicit, which means that adding no code to `x`, that lvalue expression can become an operand of an implicit conversion expression. It is the context alone that tells you whether eventually you have todo with an rvalue. You cannot decide purely based on the  contextfree characters of `x`.

Comment: The point of this is, I guess, that there may be multiple expressions that all have the same lexical representation.

Comment: @Pubby I did not state the opposite. Of course r-values have memory locations, too. And we can take r-value references. However, an r-value reference is used an immediately discarded; the point remains: one cannot "assign a value" to an r-value.

Comment: No. An r-value is anything that is being used as a source operand. An l-value is anything that is being used as a destination operand. In 'y = x', y is the l-value, x is the r-value. 'x' may well be an l-value somewhere else. These terms have no meaning other than in the context of a specific statement.